# Returning JS from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, return

I'm executing script on one site. I'd like to pass some params to php on other site (even other domain) and include JS which should be returned from php request. Is it even possible to do?

Comment: You'd need to look into JSONP or CORS.

Comment: I was thinking about AJAX, but can i use it cross-domain?

Comment: JSONP and CORS are two ways of making AJAX work cross-domain, which is why I suggested you look into them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JSON,

1. Complete processing your script on site 1, convert the variables into JSON or simply make a post request to the site on another domain.
2. Grab the JSON or post Input from site 1 and execute the the php script on site-2, now pack the output into a JSON,(don't forget to serialize/escape the output using htmlspecialchars) all you have to do is json_encode.
3. Return the output to the post request from site-1.

All of this will work. But here is the catch, you must not pass scripts over the air unless you know your script is safe. They can be intercepted and can be hacked. And the input also must be from trusted sources.
You might also want to check your CORS settings.